# why integer result in 0 when I change declared integer to string in Bash script

Tags: bash

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i number
# The script will treat subsequent occurrences of "number" as an integer.       

number=3
echo "Number = $number"     # Number = 3

number=three
echo "Number = $number"     # Number = 0
# Tries to evaluate the string "three" as an integer.
```

I cannot figure out why `number` changed when I assign a string `"three"` to `number`. I think `number` should stay the same. That really surprised me.

Comment: This is just not supported. The assignment operator does not translate english words into their numerical meaning. If it isn't a number (in digits) then `0` will result. What are you trying to do, in a wider perspective?

Comment: Why would it stay the same, you just assigned it a new value...

Comment: But assign string to a declared integer is illegal, so I think `number` should stay same just like it failed.  Set `number` to 0 destroy my original data. It is just a example from a bash script book.

Comment: no assigning a string is not illegal, it is "interpreted" as a number. e.g. `"5+5"` is interpreted as `10`. You string is interpreted as `0` as a last resort.

Comment: @geert3 Not quite a last resort; strings are (recursively) evaluated as parameter expansions in an arithmetic context; undefined parameters default to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `declare` section of `man bash`:

> `-i     The variable is treated as an integer; arithmetic evaluation (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION) is performed when the variable is assigned a value.`

From the `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section of `man bash`:

> `The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic expression when...a variable which has been given the integer attribute using declare -i is assigned a value. A null value evaluates to 0.`

Together, these clearly state that the behavior you're seeing is the expected behavior. When the characters `t` `h` `r` `e` `e` are evaluated arithmetically, the resulting `null` value is evaluated as `0`, which is then assigned to the variable `number`.

All assignments in bash are interpreted first as strings. `number=10` interprets the `1` `0` as a string first, recognizes it as a valid integer, and leaves it as-is. `number=three` is just as syntactically and semantically valid as `number=10`, which is why your script continues without any error after assigning the evaluated value of `0` to `number`.

Comment: `then casts it to an integer`, it doesn't, it's always a string.

Comment: @123 Adjusted to `recognizes it as a valid integer`.